# Generating a functional component declaration based on state - React / Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, components, state, declaration, tailwind-css

In the below code (SideBar.jsx), when a user clicks on a menu item, I capture the *title* from the *Menus* array and hold it in the *component* state.  I've console logged the *component* state and this is working as planned, when menu items are clicked.  I now want to use the value in the *component* state as the name of a component declaration elsewhere in the function, so that when the user clicks a certain menu item, it will open a corresponding .jsx functional component (e.g. HomePage.jsx, Notifications.jsx, Members.jsx, etc - determined from the previously mentioned array).

If I want to declare a functional component, then I code it as below (using Homepage as an example):

```
<HomePage />
```

So I tried doing the following to dynamically generate the declaration from the content of the *component* state:

```
<{component} />
```

But this gives me a syntax error, so I guess my approach here is wrong.

How would I go about dynamically creating the component declaration content based on the value held in the *component* state?

Code:

**App.jsx**

```
import SideBar from './components/SideBar';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SideBar />
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

**SideBar.jsx**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import HomePage from './HomePage';

function SideBar() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const [component, setComponent] = useState('');
  console.log(component)
  const Menus = [
    { id: '1', title: 'HomePage', src: 'Chart_fill' },
    { id: '2', title: 'Notifications', src: 'Chat' },
    { id: '3', title: 'Members', src: 'User', gap: true },
    { id: '4', title: 'Events', src: 'Calendar' },
    { id: '5', title: 'Staff', src: 'Search' },
    { id: '6', title: 'Services', src: 'Chart' },
    { id: '7', title: 'Reports', src: 'Folder', gap: true },
    { id: '8', title: 'Settings', src: 'Setting' },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <div
        className={` ${
          open ? 'w-72' : 'w-20 '
        } bg-dark-purple h-screen p-5  pt-8 relative duration-300`}
      >
        <img
          src={require('../assets/control.png')}
          alt="Missing Icon"
          className={`absolute cursor-pointer -right-3 top-10 w-7 border-dark-purple
           border-2 rounded-full  ${!open && 'rotate-180'}`}
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        />
        <div className="flex gap-x-4 items-center">
          <img
            src={require('../assets/logo.png')}
            alt="Missing Icon"
            className={`cursor-pointer duration-500 ${
              open && 'rotate-[360deg]'
            }`}
          />
          <h1
            className={`text-white origin-left font-medium text-xl duration-200 ${
              !open && 'scale-0'
            }`}
          >
            ADCA
          </h1>
        </div>
        <ul className="pt-6">
          {Menus.map((Menu, index) => (
            <li
              onClick={() => {
                component !== Menu.title
                  ? setComponent(Menu.title)
                  : setComponent('');
              }
              }
              key={index}
              className={`flex rounded-md p-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-light-white text-gray-300 text-sm items-center gap-x-4 
              ${Menu.gap ? 'mt-9' : 'mt-2'} ${
                index === 0 && 'bg-light-white' // sets the background overlay colour of a menu item (by index number)
              } `}
            >
              <img
                src={require(`../assets/${Menu.src}.png`)}
                alt="Missing Icon"
              />
              <span className={`${!open && 'hidden'} origin-left duration-200`}>
                {Menu.title}
              </span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="h-screen flex-1 p-7">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold ">Home Page</h1>
                
        <{component} />
   
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SideBar;
```

Comment: Hi there
Try to use routes to have components rendered based on the path
For example: You can have the HomePage component rendered when the path is '/'
Then Members component when the path is '/members'

You can use some libs to achieve that, have a look at this: https://reactrouter.com

Comment: Thanks @kleisersarifo, that did indeed solve my problem - it took a bit more coding with reactrouter, but is now working as I needed.  For some reason I can't mark your comment as an accepted answer, I'm not sure why - but I'm not very familiar with Stack Exchange yet.

Comment: @Jonathan that's because it was a comment not an answer

Comment: Glad I've steered you in the right direction. @pguardiario is right, you can only up-vote